# weighted pearson correlation coefficent with two sample sizes

Tags: r, statistics, correlation

I have a dataframe with var1 and var1 nvar1 and nvar2 I want to get the weighted square of the pearson correlation coefficent between var1 and var2 weighted by the same sizes (nvar1 and nvar2)

```
# Create a mock DataFrame
df <- data.frame(
  var1 = rnorm(100),                    
  nvar1 = sample(50:100, 100, replace = TRUE),  # Sample sizes for var1
  nvar2 = sample(50:100, 100, replace = TRUE)   # Sample sizes for var2
)

# Generate var2 based on var1 and add some noise
df$var2 <- 2 * df$var1 + rnorm(100)
```

I see this approach:

```
# Load the weights package
library(weights)
weighted_corr <- wtd.cor(df$var1, df$var2, weight = df$nvar1)
```

What I dont get is that I really have two sample sizes, should I add them up and pass them to `weights`?

Comment: A correlation is always between paired points of data, so the sample size cannot differ. The `weight` argument is a value that would be proportional to the 'sample size' of each observation, for example if they are pre-averaged from different sub-samples.

Comment: I think weights isn't being used correctly here, maybe if you explain your problem context a bit more we could suggest a better solution. Weights in the context of this function (as I understand it, I'm no expert), refers more to reweighting you would do to adjust for differences between your sample and population. I.e. lets say the first 10 data points you have need to be weighted at .5 to get your sample to reflect that proportion in the population, this is what weights is for. You can't have differing sample sizes in a correlation, i.e. your N is just the length of the vectors var1 and 2.

Comment: See this post, might be more helpful. Specifically the bottom section on whether this is really the approach you want to take: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/221246/such-thing-as-a-weighted-correlation

Comment: @BobbyThomas. Sorry hit enter to fast. I am looking at the correlation of phenotypes for different genes in two populations Say population 1 (1000 people ) has 30% phenotype A and phenotype 70% phenotype B and population 2 (10000) people has 25% phenotype A and 75% for phenotype B.  if looking at the correlation between phenotypes across many genes between population 1 and 2 I think phenotype B should have more weight compared to phenotype A in the overall correlation because there are more observations

Comment: Sure, but why do you need to weight this? Just don't aggregate the data up first and the raw amounts of the data will naturally weight the end correlation. I usually don't recommend trying to combine results of analyses without deeply understanding the properties of the analysis. i.e. don't combine two correlations without deeply understanding correlation and how to propagate uncertainty. More generally I would look deeper at why you want to aggregate this together in the first place though when it seems like you know these to be two distinct populations

Comment: And also I would still look at the link I provided to the other question. A multiple regression model might just end up fitting your research question of interest better, depending on what that research question is.